# How to search field that return many times in elasticsearch chrome extention?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch and I want to run in the Chrome extension, specific script -
the script that returns me all docs that one of their fields is counted much time in all docs.

I will be specifically -
I want to return all users from the user index, that their domain in the field doc.Users_Email exists in 5 other users or more, except "@gmail" and "@yhaoo".

How can I do that?